# Issue with command flutter run --releease, Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

In my app when I run my app in debug mode everything works fine. But when I run app with `flutter run --release` it gives me this error,

```
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Full Log from the console,

```
Note: C:\Users\Ravi\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.9.0+7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseadmob\AdRequestBuilderFactory.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: C:\Users\Ravi\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_webview_plugin-0.3.8\android\src\main\java\com\flutter_webview_plugin\WebviewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

C:\Users\Ravi\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:137: warning: [unchecked] unchecked
 cast
      return (List<String>) stream.readObject();
                                             ^
  required: List<String>
  found:    Object
C:\Users\Ravi\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:182: warning: [unchecked] unchecked
 method invocation: constructor <init> in class ArrayList is applied to given types
          List<String> listValue = new ArrayList<>((Set) value);
                                   ^
  required: Collection<? extends E>
  found: Set
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class ArrayList

C:\Users\Ravi\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:182: warning: [unchecked] unchecked
 conversion
          List<String> listValue = new ArrayList<>((Set) value);
                                                   ^
  required: Collection<? extends E>
  found:    Set
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class ArrayList
C:\Users\Ravi\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:182: warning: [unchecked] unchecked
 conversion
          List<String> listValue = new ArrayList<>((Set) value);
                                   ^
  required: List<String>
  found:    ArrayList
4 warnings
Note: C:\Users\Ravi\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.2.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\urllauncher\WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
```

I am unable to figure out that if some deprecated APIs causing this issue then why it working in debug mode? Please help me.

Comment: You could open the android folder in Android studio and do manual resync, or you could try flutter clean and  flutter build -release -v